# How to determine if an IP is up or down

Tags: nmap

I have an IP who I was told is down.
If I try to ping this IP, I can't reach it but if I launch nmap with `-Pn` option, I obtain that the IP is UP and that the 1720 port is open.

Do you think nmap is giving me false values or is the ip really UP with port 1720 open?

Comment: -Pn: Treat all hosts as online -- skip host discovery

Comment: most likely false positive.

Comment: This is a pure networking question. nmap is a general tool, not a security tool. Pings can be blocked by firewalls. There is no possible way that we can determine what is actually going on.